# Populating an array - Getting syntax error on a 'for' statement

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax-error

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting a syntax error when I try using this program.  This code worked fine when I was using populating lists, however, I've decided to use an array as I can manipulate the data to my liking.

Here is the code:

```
#Frame Creation

frames=[]

for n in range (0, (workingframes*archnodes*3)):
    frames.append( )


frames = array(frames)                                    #generates array
frames = reshape(frames, ((archnodes*3),workingframes)    #reshapes array




#Frame Population

for f in range (0, workingframes):

    if f<=(workingframes/2):

        for x in range (0, (archnodes)):
            frames[(archnodes*3)].insert((archnodes*3), (archstartred[x]))
            frames[(archnodes*3)+1].insert(((archnodes*3)+1),(archstartgrn[x]))
            frames[(archnodes*3)+2].insert(((archnodes*3)+2),(archstartblu[x]))

        for y in range (0, nodesperframe):
            archstartred.pop()
            archstartgrn.pop()
            archstartblu.pop()
            archstartred.insert(0, backred)
            archstartgrn.insert(0, backgrn)
            archstartblu.insert(0, backblu)

    else:
        for y in range (0, nodesperframe):
            archstartred.pop(0)
            archstartgrn.pop(0)
            archstartblu.pop(0)
            archstartred.append(backred)
            archstartgrn.append(backgrn)
            archstartblu.append(backblu)

        for x in range (0, (archnodes)):
            frames[(archnodes*3)].insert((archnodes*3), (archstartred[x]))
            frames[(archnodes*3)+1].insert(((archnodes*3)+1),(archstartgrn[x]))
            frames[(archnodes*3)+2].insert(((archnodes*3)+2),(archstartblu[x]))
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "backandforth3.py", line 99
    for f in range (0, workingframes):
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried using different values for 'f'.  I've tried removing the colons (which leads to other syntax errors.)  What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing closing parenthesis in the line above the one giving the error.  SyntaxErrors on the next line are a common symptom of missing parenthesis.

Comment: Also note that `frames.append( )` (line 6) is a TypeError if that ever gets executed.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that!  Thank you!

Comment: If you think that one of the below answers helped you solve your problem, you should mark it as accepted (click on the checkmark next to the answer).  That is a way of saying "this answer solved my problem" for others who may wander across this post.  It also gives some bonus reputation to the poster which is nice and makes it so the other people looking to answer questions don't spend a lot of time working on a question which has already been solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
frames = reshape(frames, ((archnodes*3),workingframes)    #reshapes array
```

You have three `(` and two `)`.  Python thinks that the reshape() call isn't over at the end of the line, so it proceeds down the file until it hits the `for` and `:`, which don't make sense inside a function call.

Comment: +1 for "Python thinks that the reshape call isn't over".  I would +1 again (if possible) if you mentioned that the reason for that is because python automatically continues lines enclosed in any sort of braces/parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Missing parens:

```
frames = reshape(frames, ((archnodes*3),workingframes)
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe it was that simple!